# Event in HTML5 form raised before validation of input fields.

Tags: forms, validation, html

Is there any event raised before the validation of fields in an HTML5 form and before the submit of this form?

AFAIK, the submit event is raised just before the submit of the form, but after the validation step, so this one fires too late for me.

**Update**: I have a textarea with the "required" property, and if the user has JS I want to substitute it by an HTML editor. The HTML editor syncs its contents with the textarea on submit (after the validation step), so for the browser the textarea is always empty. That's why I'm asking for an event fired before the validation. Any other way answer that solves this problem will be accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no event which fires before validation happens. There is only the `invalid` event, which is fired after validation of an invalid field, but before the validation UI is shown (preventing the default prevents showing the browser validation UI).

In case you want to sync two fields, you have to use two events. The first is `DOMContentReady` and the second is the `change` event.

Additional info: if you hide the invalid field element, the browser can not show the validation message to the user. You can workaround this with the following code (note this assumes that you are using jQuery 1.6x and a special structure):

```
$('textarea.wysiwyg').bind('invalid', function(e){
    //remove validation bubble
    e.preventDefault();
    //implement your own validation UI
    $(this).next('div.wysiwyg').after('<p class="error">'+ $.prop(this, 'validationMessage') +'</p>');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, this is useful information. I updated the question with more details of my real problem. If you have any idea on how to achieve what I'm trying to achieve I'll accept your answer. If there are no updates after a while I will also accept your answer, as it's strictly the right answer to my original question.