# Capture state of html5 forms using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to capture the state of an html5 form element using jquery? For example, when an email field detects that the input was not an email, does it fire an event that can be captured by jquery so that it can do something about it like disable the submit button until the correct email format has been inputted?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871428/event-in-html5-form-raised-before-validation-of-input-fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) ([alternate link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)) plugin. It does exactly what you're asking for in a simple jQuery function.

For the fields that you wish to be validated for valid emails, add `email` to the `class` attribute.