# Client side validation events and UI blocking

Tags: javascript, html, validation

We have recently started adding HTML 5 client side validation on out forms.

An interesting side effect that I ran into is this. For some forms we create an overlay with a loading indicator when the form is submitted. This is done to protect the form against multiple submissions. It also looks cool.

However, when a HTML 5 client side validation event occurs, e.g. REQUIRED, the on submit handler is triggered, and the overlay displays but b/c of the client side validation the form is not actually submitted and you're stuck.

Now, I want to avoid having to redo this kind of client side validation in Javascript. Is there any kind of event that indicates that a client side validation exception has occurred? This way, I could disable the overlay based on that event.

Comment: Are you calling the validation or is this a third party library? Event handlers are called in the order that they were added to the element, so you could call your validation first and then stopImmediatePropagation and preventDefault on the event if you find problems. This should stop the handler that adds the overlay from being called. For more details, see the jQuery docs at http://api.jquery.com

Comment: You misunderstand me. I'm talking about browser side HTML 5 validation. It's not called. You specify it in the input tag definition.

Comment: I think this may be the answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871428/event-in-html5-form-raised-before-validation-of-input-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for failing to pick up that you are using native HTML validation and not JavaScript validation. This was clear in the question but, I was obviously distracted by something else when reading through and quickly adding the comment.

You have already found the [invalid event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/invalid) from your linked question, but it is possible that there is a better solution to this than unbinding the submit handler (which would then need to be rebound to have any effect when the user corrects their error and re-submits).

You could use the [:invalid psuedo-class/selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3ainvalid) to check the form within the submit handler and ensure that all of the inputs are valid before showing the overlay. This could also be used in your stylesheets to visually highlight the error fields. The script would look something like-

```
function onFormSubmit (event) {
    console.log('Submit event fired');

    //Validation check - could use jQuery for selectors to avoid need to check querySelectorAll availability

    if ('querySelectorAll' in document) {
        var sampleForm = document.getElementById('sample-form');

        var invalidElements = sampleForm.querySelectorAll('input:invalid');

        if (invalidElements.length > 0) {
            event.preventDefault(); //Not really required - browser will stop submit
            alert('Validation failed');
            return;
        }

        //Your code - overlay
    }

    alert('Form submitted');
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/pwdst/6b2Gd/1/

It would also be possible to check the individual [validity.valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation) property of the input controls if you have a reasonably small form, which will also provide more information about the errors if this is helpful in the context of your application. You would need to select and loop through the form input elements, either using jQuery/Sizzle/querySelectors, individually checking the validity against the DOM element (not jQuery object).

As an aside, a reminder to always remember to include Server Side validation - regardless of your client method(s). This is the only environment you control and can be relied upon to execute and not be tampered with by the user.

Comment: Incidentally the "submit" event was **not** firing for me with an invalid form in current versions of Chrome.